# How to turn on logs in Flask app

Tags: python, flask, socket.io

Testing a flask-SocketIO app and I can't see any logs. It crashes but it doesn't write anything in my Konsole. What I only see is:

```
 ~/PycharmProjects/chat $ flask run
 * Serving Flask-SocketIO app "main.py"
 * Forcing debug mode off
```

Is it connected with Socket-IO library? Other Flask applications work normally and everything is shown in console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set debug to True. Do this:

```
export FLASK_APP=main.py
export FLASK_DEBUG=1
flask run
```

Now you will be able to see the verbose debug in your console.

Comment: I did it and I still can't see the traceback messages. It looks like this:
 * Serving Flask-SocketIO app "main.py"
 * Forcing debug mode on
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 399-480-796
127.0.0.1 - - [2018-08-12 04:55:32] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 323 0.001283
127.0.0.1 - - [2018-08-12 04:55:51] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 323 0.001800

Comment: these lines are shown when an error occurs

Comment: Yes, this is what you would see, the sever is returning 405 response code. If there was something in the code, it would show up.

Answer (score 2):

In the terminal, type `export FLASK_ENV=development`

The development mode on Flask enables logging functionality and also a lot of developer helpful tools.